# cross-browser zooming mechanism in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I have a graph made out of simple `<div>`s and I need to allow users to zoom in and out.  It seems that the css zoom rule that fixes so many things in IE doesn't work well or sometimes at all in other browsers.  Is there some kind of mechanism or library that I can easily allow visitors to zoom in and out of a `<div>` that contains many `<div>`s?  I tried -moz-scale for firefox and all kinds of strange things happen as you zoom, z-indexes get out of what, things don't align so well, etc.

I'm happy to make zooming a feature where you're required to use a modern browser, but at least the latest versions of firefox, chrome and IE need to be supported.  If there's an html5 feature, that's fine.

Comment: Wow. I could have asked the exact same question. I'd love to hear the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Zooming I have used CSS3 Transforms (scale(1.2) for example).  It works pretty well and is supported on IE9, Mozilla and Webkit.

Comment: Beware of Opera problems: it rasterizes, then zooms in some situations leading to nasty pixelation (eg SVG is particularly bad)

Comment: I guess that's the -moz-scale mechanism for firefox, I noticed all kinds of strange behavior.  Z-indexes got all out of whack and lines/boxes get misaligned...  I guess I need to play with that a little more.